# MPMovieController control bar not responding

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm making an iPad version of an app I've already made for iPhone, which means I know this code has worked. I am using self.bounds instead of a static value, so the size to is accordig to the docs.

The thing is: When I open a video, everything shows up as it should. However, I can't press anything on the control bar.

I can't find anobody having this problem either on google or on here...

Anyone got any idea of what the problem might be?

Tom

Code:

```
    mediaController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] observationInfo]);



    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackIsReady:)
                                                 name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification
                                               object:mediaController];

    CGRect rect = self.view.bounds;
    //mView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height - 30)];
    //mView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [mediaController.view setFrame:rect];

    [self.view addSubview:mediaController.view];
    //[self.view addSubview:mView];
    hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    hud.labelText = @"Loading video...";
    [self.view addSubview:hud];
    [hud show:YES];
    [mediaController prepareToPlay];
    mediaController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    mediaController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [mediaController.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us some code on how you create and layout the view.

Comment: There. I know the taprecognizer looks a bit spooky, but I've already tried commenting that away without result.

Comment: Does it work on the iPad if you use a static value for the frame?

Comment: Gonna try, back with report in a sec

Comment: It worked! Since this made no sense to me at all, could you please try to explaing what just happened? Feels to me like self.bounds would do the exact same thing...

Comment: Also just make an answer with this and I'll accept it. Thanks man! :)

Comment: Um...I really don't know what's happening. I figured that since the static value was the only thing you changed, it would provide a clue. What you can do is change it back to using bounds and then inspect the frame values to see if it matches your static value. It could be that your self.view's bounds is wrong.

Comment: Make sure your code is not called before the view has valid bounds. That is, it needs to be called at or after `viewDidAppear`.